# Can you parameterize sort order in a sql server prepared statement?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, prepared-statement

I've got a .Net web system with a VB.Net front end talking to a SQL Server 2005 back end over ADO.Net.  Essentially, what I want to do is this:

```
Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("", connection)
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM someTable ORDER BY orderValue @SortOrder"
Dim sortParam As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@SortOrder", SqlDbType.varChar, 3)
sortParam.Value = "ASC"
command.Parameters.Add(sortParam)
command.Prepare()
reader = command.ExecuteReader()
```

Where the sort order would be passed in via a query string or some such.  This code throws  "Incorrect syntax near '@SortOrder'. Statement(s) could not be prepared."

Is this even possible, or do I have some really dumb syntax error I'm not seeing?

(And, yes, the client is only running .net 2.0, so LINQ-based solutions won't work, sadly.

Thanks, all!

Update / Response:

Well, that's what I thought.  Thanks for the sanity check, everybody.  (For some context, the command string is currently being built dynamically, but we're moving the system in a more prepared statement direction, and this was one of the edge cases I didn't know was possible.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that won't work.

There are two possibilities that I can think of right off the top of my head to do what you're trying to do:

1. Build the SQL string dynamically
2. Return a Data Table from your query, and then use a View to do your sorting.

---

With another 6 years or so of experience (plus SQL Server Versions), I have a way of accomplishing this.

```
DECLARE @SortByIdASC AS INT;
SET @SortByIdASC = 1;
WITH cte AS (
SELECT Id, Foo, Bar
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id ASC) AS IdSortAsc
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS IdSortDesc 
   FROM MyTable
)

SELECT Id, Foo, Bar
   FROM cte 
   ORDER BY CASE WHEN @SortByIdASC = 1 THEN IdSortAsc
                 WHEN @SortByIdASC = 2 THEN IdSortDesc 
                 ELSE ''
                 END 
           , Foo, Bar
```

This also allows for Sorting up,down, or even excluding that particular column from the given sort order.

Comment: Be careful implementing the dynamic SQL strings, SQL injection. Preferred would be sorting in the view or one of the suggestions with the case statements. It might be a tad slower, but often that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to update the columns used in a sort. Take the following example:

```
declare @fname int,@lname int

select @fname=1,@lname=0

select * from [user]
order by case when @Fname=1 then firstname when @lname=1 then lastname end
```

I don't think you can use this technique to modify the sort order but you can at least change the columns your sorting on. At least when I try get complaints about syntax with SQL 2005

Answer (score 2):

You can in a similar manner to an existing post.

```
declare @firstSortField int, @secondSortField int
set @firstSortField = 1
set @secondSortField = 3

select firstName, lastName, phoneNumber
from customers
order by 
    case @firstSortField when 1 then firstName when 2 then lastName when 3 then phoneNumber else null end, 
    case @secondSortField when 1 then firstName when 2 then lastName when 3 then phoneNumber else null end
```

Comment: Yes but he wants to change sort order not the field;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, only parameter values can be prepared.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you'd need to build it into the SQL query each time, or if you have a sub set of sort orders, cache the command object for these and re-use as suites.

The short ansswer to the question though is "No"

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you asked, and never puts user-entered strings anywhere near the database.

```
//get the requested order from the query string
string sortOrderRequest = request["SortOrder"].ToUpper();
string sortParam = "";
if ( sortOrderRequest.Equals("ASC"))
  sortParam = " order by ordervalue ASC ";
else if (sortOrderRequest.Equals("DESC"))
  sortParam = " order by ordervalue DESC ";

Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("", connection)
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM someTable " + sortParam;
command.Prepare()
reader = command.ExecuteReader()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure can do. Create two aliased columns, SortASC and SortDESC, fill these with whatever you want, and sort on them.

```
-- Testcase setup
DECLARE @OrderASC bit
SET @OrderASC = 0

-- Statement required
SELECT
    Users.*,
    CASE @OrderASC WHEN 1 THEN Users.Alias ELSE null END AS _SortASC,
    CASE @OrderASC WHEN 0 THEN Users.Alias ELSE null END AS _SortDESC
FROM Users
ORDER BY _SortASC, _SortDESC DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended the accepted answer to reach an effective solution for parameterizing order clause in a SQL query. Here is a sample code :

```
DECLARE @Sorting VARCHAR(200) = 'CreationTime ASC'

SELECT v.*, 
CASE WHEN @Sorting = 'CreationTime ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v.CreationTime ASC) 
     WHEN @Sorting = 'CreationTime DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v.CreationTime DESC) 
                                         ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY v.Id ASC) END AS rownum

FROM Vehicles v ORDER BY rownum
```